# MSSQL: Select records where updated_at-created_at > 2 minutes

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to select all rows of which created_at (datetime) - updated_at (datetime) > 2 minutes ?

I used something like this but the diff is in bigint and not reliable:

```sql
SELECT TOP (1000) 
    [id], 
    [created_at], 
    [updated_at], 
    CAST(
        CAST([updated_at]-[created_at] as timestamp) as bigint
    ) as diff
  FROM [dbo].[VoicePasswordReset] 
    WHERE CAST( CAST([updated_at]-[created_at] as timestamp) as bigint) > 360 
    ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

Received records:

```
id                                      created_at              updated_at              diff
d9932bac-fd87-42a3-b647-8e334c016b1a    2023-06-02 12:03:36.267 2023-06-02 12:04:37.000 18220
b99cc8f4-99bc-4833-95a8-76c8e14c77b1    2023-06-02 10:36:52.837 2023-06-02 10:37:44.000 15349
fa076677-54fc-45ae-8de5-6d68fc782b74    2023-06-02 08:57:49.397 2023-06-02 08:58:51.000 18481
b63f58d4-ce5e-4c44-8649-60690efac0d7    2023-06-02 08:10:43.020 2023-06-02 08:11:48.000 19494
eb3b2b5f-11dc-4221-b05d-be83e1701b30    2023-06-02 07:58:53.483 2023-06-02 07:59:12.000 5555
46d0b1f3-74d4-4cd0-be2f-3baed2fd9ac9    2023-06-02 07:53:07.370 2023-06-02 07:53:17.000 2889
b0264169-4d64-4470-95b1-58a3867b5717    2023-06-02 07:51:27.000 2023-06-02 07:52:05.000 11400
```

Comment: What are the data types of those fields? What level of time granularity do you need?...`seconds`?

Comment: you can use DATEDIFF(mi,created_Date,updated_Date)

Comment: BTW `timestamp` in SQL Server has nothing to do with dates and times. This is a binary value (deprecated synonym for [`rowversion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16))

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting the difference between the values I would do it as

```
WHERE updated_at < DATEADD(MINUTE, 2, created_at)
```

i.e. just add 2 minutes to the value to get a value that can be used in a comparison.

This ensures that the correct rows are returned.

For the `diff` column you would probably want `DATEDIFF` but you need to understand that this doesn't calculate the difference as a time interval and then return the date part of that interval.

It just [returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) the "the count ... of the specified datepart boundaries crossed".

```
DATEDIFF(YEAR, '2023-12-31 23:59:59', '2024-01-01 00:00:00') /*Returns 1*/
```

So you might prefer to get the `DATEDIFF` in `MILLISECOND` and then do your own rounding to get results that better reflect the actual time difference between the values.